# VBA/EXCEL Split file every x rows with if statement equal value have to be in the same file

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying split one excel file for several which every will have max. 1500 rows and in row B I have numbers which can be equal but we have to split file if 1501 row have same value as 1500 and cut on the first value.
Here you can see example of file which i want to split: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19SGHZSBrNbteMbCeZYqsq9g9ddsnwFKrdSsHA51olQg/edit#gid=0 
IMAGE: https://postimg.org/image/f5tqjwied/[image: sample data]

Here we should have 2 files first to 1483 row and second from 1484 to end. Of course with header.

Code:

```
    Option Explicit


Sub SplitRowsToFiles()

  Dim hdrSize As Integer: hdrSize = 1
  Dim blkSize As Integer:  blkSize = 1000 - hdrSize
  Dim maxLimit As Integer: maxLimit = 500

  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
  Dim saveFile As String, name As String
  Dim WR As Range, header As Range

  Set wrkSht = ActiveSheet
  Set header = wrkSht.Rows("1:" & hdrSize)

  saveFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename

  Dim last As Integer
  With wrkSht.UsedRange
    last = .Rows.Count
  End With

  Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
  Dim limit As Integer, part As Integer
  part = 0
  i = hdrSize + 1 ' skip the header

  Do While True

    j = i + blkSize - 1
    If j <= last Then
      ' process from blkSize to blkSize+maxLimit rows
      limit = j + maxLimit
      Do While Cells(j, "b") = Cells(j - 1, "b") And _
      j < limit And j < last
        j = j + 1
      Loop
    Else
      ' otherwise process up to the last row
      j = last
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

     Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
     Set WR = wrkSht.Rows(i & ":" & j)

     header.Copy wb.Worksheets(1).Rows("1:" & hdrSize)
     WR.Copy wb.Worksheets(1).Rows(hdrSize + 1)

     part = part + 1
     name = saveFile & part & ".xls"
     wb.SaveAs Filename:=name, FileFormat:=xlExcel8, CreateBackup:=False
     wb.Close

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    i = j + 1
    If i > last Then Exit Do

  Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: For security reason we prefer not to download data fro an external link. Would you provide a sample of your data as a picture or formatted table.

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/f5tqjwied/ <- image, but this file which I create on google sheet is just clean data, also added to main question

Answer (score 0):

Try changing these values:

```
Dim blkSize As Integer:  blkSize = 1483 - hdrSize
Dim maxLimit As Integer: maxLimit = 0
```

Comment: Unfortunately nothing change

Comment: What is your output?

Comment: 1483 rows in file but one file have equal value in column B for 2 files but they should be union in one file

Comment: Well if you want to have Rows (2 - 1483) in first file, and Rows (1484 - end)  in second file, the changes above should do that. If they don't work for you follow these steps. Save your document as a macro free document (Save as Type : Excel Workbook). Close all workbooks. Open your recently saved workbook and copy paste your code in a new module (with the changes I suggested). This should work.

Comment: but this isn't a problem. I believe that is misunderstood. My script works fine if we r talking about split in 1500 row but this file should be split in row 1483 because of loop Do While Cells(j, "b") = Cells(j - 1, "b") And _
      j < limit And j < last, that mens if i have same equal in following and previous rows then i have to cut in line where they are different, in our example in line 1483